# Java - sometimes, objects are not updated in multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a an issue that's very weird to me.

I'm writing a multithreaded client-server framework, and so far, it works pretty well, *except one thing*.

Consider the following image:

[image]

The client can request tasks, which are added to a queue. If any elements are in this queue, they are polled and added to an "executing" queue. The task in question is then executed on a separate thread using an `ExecutorService`.

The "executing" queue is checked for tasks that has completed whatever it is they're doing, and moved to a "completed" queue. This queue is checked, and replies are dispatched to the appropriate clients.

This all works, except when there are more than *one* task running in the system.

Each task is held in a `TaskRequest` object and each task can refer back to its "host" `TaskRequest`. However, it appears as though the reference from the task is *different* from the reference of the... well... actual `TaskRequest`

On the image, I've highlighted the `TaskRequest` and the `resultBag` to show they have different addresses and IDs.

This, as I mentioned, is only the case when more than one task is in the system and it is beyond flabbergasting to me.

The `complete` field is not updating, despite me having checked this by outputting value of the variable after it is set.

Why is the "host" object not updating?

Below is the code for the classes in question, Pastebinned to reduce space.

[TaskRequest code](http://pastebin.com/YiPCT6s0)

[TaskBase code (extended by other tasks)](http://pastebin.com/nch67QK1)

[TaskQueue code (keeping of all the tasks, requested, executing and completed, respectively)](http://pastebin.com/grM9gLC9)

[TaskExecutor code (running over the TaskQueue instance, executing tasks, etc)](http://pastebin.com/M7tMG6hk)

I am sorry for posting a bit of a wall of text.

Comment: Are you fields `volatile`?

Comment: I tried making some of them volatile (the ones that don't update), but it didn't help.